# Rad Upload control | Add tooltip on browse button

Tags: upload, controls, rad

I want to add tooltip to my Rad upload control browse button. Anyone knows about it or have worked on this before please reply

Answer (score 0):

See this Telerik example:
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/localization-upload-client-side.html

For the select/browse button just include a title value for the input button
input.title = "This is the add more files button";